# Uploading Multiple files or directories

Tags: html

I would like to give a user the option to upload either a single file, multiple files or a directory. I would like to do this from the one file chooser. I was able to get this working with 2 by using the following tags:

`<p>Directory: <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory /></p>`
`<p>Multiple: <input type="file" multiple /></p>`

However this requires the user to click on a different button depending on whether they are uploading files or a directory.

Is it possible to get this functionality with 1 file chooser?

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/26szvfgk/3/

Comment: please check this manual, if it helps you http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I already have the backend in place and working - my question is relating to the HTML tags. Using the first tag will not allow you to select only 1 file and using the second tag will not allow you to select a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should add square brackets to the name of the input. In your example, I can see that you forgot to include the name of the file input.  `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />`